# How to show that the image of a complete metric space under an isometry is closed?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\,\,:\,\, (M,d) \rightarrow (N,\sigma)$ be an isometry, that is 
$$
\sigma(f(x),f(y))=d(x,y)
$$
for all $x,y \in M$.

If $(M,d)$ is complete, show that $f(M)$ is closed in $(N,\sigma)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $y\in N$ be a limit point of $f(M)$.  Then there's a sequence $(f(x_n))\in f(M)$ converging to $y$.  Then $(f(x_n))$ is Cauchy in $(N,\sigma)$.  Since $f$ is an isometry,  $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $(M,d)$.  Since $(M,d)$ is complete,  $(x_n)$ converges to $x\in M$.  Then $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=y$.  Thus $y\in f(M)$.  So $f(M)$ is closed.

A slicker way would be to note that an isometry is a homeomorphism, and a complete space is closed.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y\in N$. If $x_n\in M$ such that $f(x_n)\to y$, then $\{f(x_n)\}_n$ is convergent, hence is Cauchy, hence $\{x_n\}_n$ is Cauchy, hence is convergent to some $x$. Then $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ and so $y=f(x)$.